# Find a differential equation, not involving time and solve to find a implicit equation for this dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, self-learning, implicit-differentiation

**Question**

[image]

I am concerned with part c) of this question.

In part b I found there to be 5 critical points at

$$(0,0) , \quad (0,-2) , \quad (2,0) , \quad (2,-2) , \quad (1,-1)$$

And linearizing around these point I find

At $(0,0)$: $\pmatrix{-2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2}$,

at $(0,-2)$: $\pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2}$

at $(2,0)$: $\pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2}$

at $(2,-2)$: $\pmatrix{-2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2}$

at $(1,-1)$: $\pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0}$

And from this I found that the crit points $(2,0)$ and $(0,-2)$ are unstable

$(0,0)$ and $(2,-2)$ are stable

and $(1,-1)$ is a saddle

Now for part c) I really don't know what it is asking me to do

Does it want me to find an equation for what $x$ and $y$ are equal to in the linearized system?

Any hints as to what the question means would be very helpful

Comment: @Moo Yeah I think I've done that and I end up with the solution $(y+1)^2 = x^2 - 2x +1 + C$ where $C$ is a consant

Comment: So they're the same? That solution just has the constant different? I don't know how they got to that solution to be honest

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. You get that $\frac{1}{2} ln|y^2 + 2y| = \frac{1}{2}ln|x^2-2x| + c$. But I don't understand what wolfram have done with the constant etc

Answer (score 1):

A hint for c):

If a prime denotes differentiation with respect to $x$ one has
$$y'={\dot y\over\dot x}\ .$$

Comment: I don’t know what the question wants me to do tho

Comment: @Gragbow: Just what Christian told you: write down what $y'=\dot y/\dot x=\dots$ is, and then solve that equation for $y(x)$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Hi Hans, yeah I eventually understood what he meant haha. I speak to Moo about it in the comments of the original post. Thank you!!